# OpenCV - cvQueryFrame()

Tags: c++, opencv

In the OpenCV reference manual: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

It states the following regarding: `cvQueryFrame( )`:

> The returned image should not be
>   released or modified by the user.

What is meant by this statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

According to source type (camera/file, codec) `cvQueryFrame` may be using the same memory area for the images captured successively. If you try to deallocate or modify an image returned by `cvQueryFrame` or `cvRetrieveFrame`, capture code from OpenCV may stop functioning properly.

This means that you shouldn't attempt to release image memory returned from these functions, for example by calling `cvReleaseImage`. The library will do this for you when needed.

Also it means that you shouldn't modify the image by using `cvScale`, `cvSet` type of functions or by changing low level pixel data directly. If you want to modify the acquired image before using it, use `cvCloneImage` to create a seperate copy for yourself.

Comment: You just saved me life.